# joomla user registered through CB is not assigned to k2 user group

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-k2, joomla-community-builder

In one of my joomla 2.5 site i am using community builder registration form.When registration completed by user who clicked confirmation link in email, the user is not assigned to k2 user group.

I set that k2 user group in k2
`parameters->advanced setting->Select the default K2 User Group for new registrations`
dropdown so that new registered user will be assigned to that group.

But it's not working.I have all required plugins enabled while i was searching through google.com for solution

Any solutions and suggestions from experts are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this when searching for a similar problem: gavick's facebook login didn't assign k2 usergroup. I suspect the solution is the same.

Edit:
/plugins/users/k2/k2.php

replace in function "onLoginUser":

```
// Get the user id
            $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            $db->setQuery("SELECT id FROM #__users WHERE username = ".$db->Quote($user['username']));
            $id = $db->loadResult();
```

with:

```
// Get the user id
            $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            $db->setQuery("SELECT id FROM #__users WHERE username = ".$db->Quote($user['username']));
            $id = $db->loadResult();

            $db->setQuery("SELECT username FROM #__users WHERE username = ".$db->Quote($user['username']));
            $mytempusername = $db->loadResult();
```

And replace:

```
$row->set('userID', $id);
$row->set('userName', $mytempusername);
$row->set('group', $params->get('K2UserGroup', 1));
```

with:

```
$row->set('userID', $id);
//$row->set('userName', $user['fullname']);
$row->set('userName', $mytempusername);
$row->set('group', $params->get('K2UserGroup', 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

work perfect only the right code for remplace in k2 2.6.6 is

```
$row->set('userID', $tmp->id);
$row->set('userName', $tmp->name);
$row->set('group', $params->get('K2UserGroup', 1));
```